# Running RoR2 application via unicorn or thin gives gem missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Hullo,

The following issue has really been bothering me much of late. I haven't been able to figure out exactly why it exists.

I have a `Rails 2` application, specifically `Rails 2.3.5`, built that I am trying to deploy on a development machine running Ubuntu 10.10. I have set up everything properly, to the best of my knowledge. Here's some proof:

```
ayaz@ubuntu$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
ayaz@ubuntu$ gem -v
1.3.7
ayaz@ubuntu$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
ayaz@ubuntu$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/ayaz/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
ayaz@ubuntu$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
atomic (1.1.10)
daemons (1.1.9)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
i18n (0.6.4)
kgio (2.8.0)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.7.7)
rack (1.5.2, 1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
raindrops (0.11.0)
rake (10.1.0)
thin (1.5.1)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
unicorn (4.6.3)
```

If I run the application via `script/server`, it runs fine:

```
ayaz@ubuntu$ script/server 
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-07-28 01:10:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-07-28 01:10:37] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23) [i686-linux]
```

However, if I run it, say, via [unicorn](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn) or [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), I keep getting this `gem` error:

```
ayaz@ubuntu$ thin start
>> Using rails adapter
Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

`unicorn_rails` gives the same error. Now, I've looked around and found suggestions about adding a `require "rubygems"` beforehand. I have tried it: I have added the line at the top of `config/boot.rb` as well as `config/environment.rb`, but to no avail.

Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks much!

Comment: have you specified 'rails' gem in environment.rb?

Comment: @SachinSingh: Thanks. Yes, I've tried adding `gem rails` in `config/environment.rb` as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that you have multiple versions of ruby/rubygems running (via RVM or rbenv for example). This might help you determine which ruby is actually used:

```
which ruby

which gem
```